# JNDI implementation returned null

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jndi

I ma facing a strange issue.
I am working on maven-web application using spring.
I am getting this error

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JNDI object with 
>    [java:/varun] not found: JNDI implementation returned null

Bellow is my `context-datasource.xml` where `JNDI` is defined.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/varun"/>
</bean>
```

Bellow is my `datasource-ds.xml` content which is present in `jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy` directory

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>varun</jndi-name>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:sid</connection-url>
    <user-name>userName</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
 <min-pool-size>25</min-pool-size> 
    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>     
 <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>    
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Every thing is configured correct Why ,**Because some time it works and some time it does not, trust me.**
Without any changes some time it works and some time it does not.

That is why I am confused Why I am facing this issue,

**What could be the possible reasons for this issue and how do i solve it?.**

Update 1:

Let me put my `web.xml`, `jboss-web.xml` and `context-datasource.xml` contents

**`web.xml`**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
                         "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>com.javaetmoi.core.spring.JBoss5XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/spring-batch-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
  
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>MainController</servlet-name>
  <display-name>MainController</display-name>
  <servlet-class>com.globalss.dnb.monitor.job.controller.MainController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MainController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MainController/StartBatch</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MainController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MainController/StopBatch</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
  <resource-ref>
   <description>WebApp DataSource</description>
   <res-ref-name>varun</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**`jboss-web.xml`**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
  <loader-repository>
       org.myapp:loader=myWebApp.war
      <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false
      </loader-repository-config>
   </loader-repository>
 </class-loading>
 
 <resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>varun</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <jndi-name>java:/varun</jndi-name>
 </resource-ref>
 
</jboss-web>
```

**`context-datasource.xml`**

```html
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/varun"/>
    </bean>  



<!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/varun"/>
 </bean> -->
```

Everything looks fine for me, But I dont know whats wrong and why, I am getting the above error.

Comment: I think if you want to declare the datasource in that way, you have to change the value attribute to `java:comp/env/jdbc/varun` or `java:comp/env/varun`.

Comment: as u suggest I did the same thing but, it does not work. I am getting the same error

Comment: i edited my answer. now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**web.xml**

You should add the following to your web.xml.

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>varun</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Then, you must create jboss-web.xml under WEB-INF folder.

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>

    <resource-ref>

        <res-ref-name>varun</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:/varun</jndi-name>

    </resource-ref>

</jboss-web>
```

And change your **datasource bean** to:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/varun"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: As you have mentioned , every thing is @ it placed in `web.xml` ,  `jboss-web.xml` and datasource bean.. But I really dont know why its not working